# implementing loops in a c brainfuck interpreter

Tags: c, interpreter, brainfuck

I have written a simple brainfuck interpreter in c. all the commands work fine, except for loops. currently, I am handeling them like this:

I have a function to find the matching square bracket:

```
int findbracket(char *commands, int currentpos){
    int lb = 0;
    int rb = 0;

    for(int i = currentpos; i != strlen(commands); ++i){
        if(commands[i] == '[') ++lb;
        if(commands[i] == ']') ++rb;

        if(lb == rb){
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

and the I have a stack to keep track of all the brackets:

```
void interpret(char *commands){
    int stack[10];
    int top = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(commands); ++i){
        char command = commands[i];
        
        //other commands...
        else if(command == '['){
            if(*ptr == 0){
                i = findbracket(commands, i);
            }
            else{
                stack[top] = i;
                ++top;
            }
        }
        else if(command == ']'){
            if(*ptr != 0){
                i = stack[top];
            }
            else{
                --top;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

however, this doesn't seem to work. for example, when executing hello world: `++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++.` it gives no output at all. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Explain what "doesn't seem to work" means. Add an example of some input, the expected result, and the actual result. Consider putting together a [mcve] so we can see the full picture.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I added an example of code not getting interpreted the right way

Comment: Perhaps click the link for [mcve] and see what's expected. Since the code you've shown does not attempt to produce any output it makes perfect sense that none is generated. You might consider explaining your example for the benefit of the folks that could help you solve your issue but don't know anything about brainfuck. I don't know what the example given is supposed to do, you say it's a "hello world" example, but I wouldn't expect that to need any loops which is what you seem to be asking about.

Comment: While I agree that the asker should have provided a bit more information, the above comment seems to be looking for a problem where there is none. The question is easy to understand and contains everything needed for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
            if(*ptr != 0){
                i = stack[top-1];
            }
```

"top" marks where the next thing will go on the stack, just above where the last thing was added.